# Three paths $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ s.t. $\alpha * \beta * \gamma$ is a closed path in homology

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

This is exercise 4.15 in Rotman's "Introduction to algebraic topology". It says:

Let $X$ be a space and let $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ be (not necessarily closed) paths in $X$ such that $\alpha * \beta * \gamma$ is defined, and a closed path. Prove that, in $H_1(X),$

$cls(\alpha*\beta *\gamma)=cls(\alpha + \beta + \gamma)= cls(\alpha)+cls(\beta)+cls(\gamma).$

I think the author means that $cls(f)$ is the homology class of a path $f$. But for that to happen, $f$ should be a cycle, which is not necessarily the case for $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$, as these need not be closed paths. What am I missing?

Comment: Well it's true in $C_1(X)$ that $\alpha * \beta * \gamma$ is equal to $\alpha + \beta + \gamma$ up to a boundary even when the paths aren't closed, but to take a homology class the path needs to be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that the second equality is only for paths $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ that are closed, since otherwise as you point out, it makes no sense.